# Group date as month

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have an SQL timestamp field and I need to group it by month like

Jan, Feb, Mar, ... but in numbers (01, 02, 03, ...)

I've tried

```
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(i.push_date, '%Y-%m')
```

But it's not working.

Comment: that should work. you will have to post an actual, complete query and some sample data if you want help.

Comment: Do you actually want to group by year+month or just month?

Comment: Do you want it grouped by year and month, or solely month?

Comment: Whoa, two Gregs asking nearly the same question. At first I thought I had double-posted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the Month() method.

```
Select Month(<field>) from <table> group by Month(<column>);
```

what you get back will be the month in number form.  You might to group by month and year which would be:

```
Select Year(<column), Month(<field>) from <table> group by Month(<column>), Year(<column>);
```

[Date/Time Functions for MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
GROUP BY YEAR(i.push_date), MONTH(i.push_date)
```